# libguile-dbd-sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: shared-library

I've compiled both guile-dbi guile-dbd-sqlite and using standard

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

and I've try to open database using scheme:

```
(define db-obj (dbi-open "sqlite3" "notes.db"))
```

but I got error:

> libguile-dbd-sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

the file is located in `/usr/local/lib` it's symbolic link to libguile-dbd-sqlite3.so.2.0.6

I'm using Xubuntu 16.10 and those packages are not in repository.

Comment: this solve the issue [Where does Ubuntu look for shared libraries?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350068/where-does-ubuntu-look-for-shared-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but perhaps the latest code solves this problem. A patch to fix shared-library loading was just published.

The gna.org website is defunct; see https://github.com/opencog/guile-dbi for the latest and greatest.